# Reset all checkbox in Android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am doing a checkbox activity where it saves the checkbox state and have a button to reset all the checkbox.

I'm stuck on how to unchecked all the checked checkbox. 
I have found the code on how to do it but nothing happened when i click the button. I tried to do 1 checkbox first but didn't succeed. Did i do something wrong?

The unchecked code that i tried to do is down below all the code.

here is my code:

```
public class PreDiveBK extends Activity implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
Button btn;
CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4, cb5, cb6, cb7, cb8, cb9, cb10, cb11, cb12, cb13,
        cb14, cb15, cb16, cb17, cb18, cb19, cb20, cb21, cb22, cb23, cb24;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.predbk);

    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    cb1.setChecked(getFromSP("cb1"));
    cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
    cb2.setChecked(getFromSP("cb2"));
    cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
    cb3.setChecked(getFromSP("cb3"));
    cb3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);
    cb4.setChecked(getFromSP("cb4"));
    cb4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb5);
    cb5.setChecked(getFromSP("cb5"));
    cb5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb6);
    cb6.setChecked(getFromSP("cb6"));
    cb6.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb7);
    cb7.setChecked(getFromSP("cb7"));
    cb7.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb8 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb8);
    cb8.setChecked(getFromSP("cb8"));
    cb8.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb9 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb9);
    cb9.setChecked(getFromSP("cb9"));
    cb9.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb10 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb10);
    cb10.setChecked(getFromSP("cb10"));
    cb10.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb11 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb11);
    cb11.setChecked(getFromSP("cb11"));
    cb11.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb12 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb12);
    cb12.setChecked(getFromSP("cb12"));
    cb12.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb13 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb13);
    cb13.setChecked(getFromSP("cb13"));
    cb13.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb14 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb14);
    cb14.setChecked(getFromSP("cb14"));
    cb14.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb15 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb15);
    cb15.setChecked(getFromSP("cb15"));
    cb15.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb16 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb16);
    cb16.setChecked(getFromSP("cb16"));
    cb16.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb17 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb17);
    cb17.setChecked(getFromSP("cb17"));
    cb17.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb18 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb18);
    cb18.setChecked(getFromSP("cb18"));
    cb18.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb19 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb19);
    cb19.setChecked(getFromSP("cb19"));
    cb19.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb20 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb20);
    cb20.setChecked(getFromSP("cb20"));
    cb20.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb21 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb21);
    cb21.setChecked(getFromSP("cb21"));
    cb21.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb22 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb22);
    cb22.setChecked(getFromSP("cb22"));
    cb22.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb23 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb23);
    cb23.setChecked(getFromSP("cb23"));
    cb23.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    cb24 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb24);
    cb24.setChecked(getFromSP("cb24"));
    cb24.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}

private boolean getFromSP(String key) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}

private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.cb1:
            saveInSp("cb1", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb2:
            saveInSp("cb2", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb3:
            saveInSp("cb3", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb4:
            saveInSp("cb4", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb5:
            saveInSp("cb5", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb6:
            saveInSp("cb6", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb7:
            saveInSp("cb7", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb8:
            saveInSp("cb8", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb9:
            saveInSp("cb9", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb10:
            saveInSp("cb10", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb11:
            saveInSp("cb11", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb12:
            saveInSp("cb12", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb13:
            saveInSp("cb13", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb14:
            saveInSp("cb14", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb15:
            saveInSp("cb15", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb16:
            saveInSp("cb16", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb17:
            saveInSp("cb17", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb18:
            saveInSp("cb18", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb19:
            saveInSp("cb19", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb20:
            saveInSp("cb20", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb21:
            saveInSp("cb21", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb22:
            saveInSp("cb22", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb23:
            saveInSp("cb23", isChecked);
            break;
        case R.id.cb24:
            saveInSp("cb24", isChecked);
            break;
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predbkReset);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                cb1.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move these lines to the end of the **onCreate** Method

```
 btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predbkReset);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (cb1.isChecked()) {
            cb1.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

your **onClick** method doesn't make sense,cause you didn't set any onClick listener

Answer (score 0):

You register a listener to the `Button R.id.predbkReset` in the method `public void onClick(View v)`, but you do not call this method. Because of that your listener is never registered and you will not get informed, once you click on the button.

Try to refactor your code:

1. Rename the method `public void onClick(View v)` to e.g. `public void initResetButton()`

   ```
   public void initResetButton() {
       cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
       btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.predbkReset);
       btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if (cb1.isChecked()) {
                  cb1.setChecked(false);
               }
           }
       });
      }
   ```
2. In your `onCreate`-method call the new `initResetButton`-method:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.predbk);
       initResetButton();

       // Your other stuff
   }
   ```